# VirtualBox freezes when using anything but NAT

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-10.04, virtual-machine, ubuntu-11.04

I have an Ubuntu(10.04.3 64bit server) guest VM on an ubuntu(11.04 64bit desktop) host.
The guest VM defaulted to the first network adapter as NAT.
Now I want to enable bridged mode, but every other configuration besides NAT freezes the VM in startup.

Ive tried giving virtualbox SU-privileges but the problem persisted.

any tips or tricks?

Screenshot:[image: Vbox Freeze]

After a few minutes, the manager starts displaying the following:
[image]

From here on nothing happens, the VM itself is frozen and cannot be closed, the vm managed can be closed but 2 processes stay open which prevent it from being opened again, I assume the problem lies within these processes:
VBoxSVC & VBoxXPCOMIPCD 
[image]

Log file content(last few lines of log):

```
00:00:00.555 VDInit finished
00:00:00.555 AIOMgr: Endpoint for file '/home/madmaze/VirtualBox VMs/redmine/redmine.vdi' (flags 000c0723) created successfully
00:00:00.566 AHCI: LUN#0: disk, PCHS=16383/16/63, total number of sectors 16777216
00:00:00.567 AHCI: LUN#0: using async I/O
00:00:00.567 AHCI ATA: LUN#0: disk, PCHS=16383/16/63, total number of sectors 16777216
00:00:00.567 AHCI ATA: LUN#1: no unit
00:00:00.567 AHCI ATA: Ctl: finished processing RESET
00:00:00.567 AHCI ATA: LUN#2: no unit
00:00:00.567 AHCI ATA: LUN#3: no unit
00:00:00.567 AHCI ATA: Ctl: finished processing RESET
00:00:00.567 AHCI ATA: Ctl: finished processing RESET
00:00:00.567 AHCI ATA: Ctl: finished processing RESET
00:00:00.567 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#0: no unit
00:00:00.567 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#1: no unit
00:00:00.567 DrvBlock: Flushes will be ignored
00:00:00.567 DrvBlock: Async flushes will be passed to the disk
00:00:00.568 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#2: CD/DVD, total number of sectors 0, passthrough disabled
00:00:00.568 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#3: no unit
00:00:00.568 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#0: finished processing RESET
00:00:00.568 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: finished processing RESET
00:00:00.579 New value of somaxconn: 1
00:00:00.579 NAT: value of BindIP has been ignored
00:00:00.579 IntNet#0: szNetwork={HostInterfaceNetworking-eth0} enmTrunkType=3 szTrunk={eth0} fFlags=0x8000 cbRecv=325632 cbSend=196608 fIgnoreConnectFailure=false
```

Comment: Try opening up VirtualBox, editing the setting from NAT to bridged, saving the settings, and then closing VirtualBox completely. Then re-launch VB and see if the setting persists or is reset to NAT. That might give a clue as to if the configuration change is actually being saved or not, and might help isolate the cause.

Comment: I can confirm that the settings are being saved, I changed it, saved, closed, opened and checked. And settings persisted

Comment: Do the Zombie processes shown in your screenshot keep running after you close VirtualBox completely? If they keep running it may be worth it to try a restart on the host.

Comment: yes they do, and ive tried restarts as well but no change.

Comment: So i have eliminated the guest as the problem, any VM I start, only starts successfully if I have NAT selected

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to recompile your VirtualBox kernel module to me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same scenario, using Ubuntu 64 Bit and many guests, all were working with no problems, until I started to do a lot of things with `qemu`.

I recall I inserted the `kvm` and `kvm_intel` modules.

- I could fix it by removing them using `rmmod` or `modprobe -r`.
- Another workaround was to unload the `vboxnetflt` module and reinstalling VirtualBox, but the first was the key.